# App Store Connect Upload Error "You haven't been given access to cloud-managed distribution certificates"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, code-signing

Uploading an iOS app to App Store Connect with Xcode (Automatically manage signing) and received this error:

[image: Screenshot of Xcode error dialog]

The following errors occurred while locating and generating signing assets. ...

Communication with Apple failed.
You haven't been given access to cloud-managed distribution certificates. Please contact your team's Account Holder or an Admin to give you access. If you need further assistance, contact Apple Developer Program Support at https://developer.apple.com/support

I have checked:

- the cert is installed and valid
- I have access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you have the Admin rights, you can enable this for anyone with Developer role if you

1. Go to App Store Connect https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/
2. Select the "Users and Access" tab
3. Select the right person and under Additional Resources, check both

- `Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` and
- `Access to Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate`.

[image: AdditionalResources]

If you don't have the Admin rights, you have to ask someone from your organization with Admin rights to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the problem.

Comment: this worked, I requested my client that change my account role to Admin to more control app.

Comment: Just an important WARNING!!!, allowing access to Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate to multiple developer accounts will mess up old builds, since every time Xcode signs it will take the developer's host computer in consideration to sign the app, and if the private keys are different, previous apps coded by another developer will start to fail.

Comment: It hasn't solved my problem. I've tried to logout from my Apple ID account in Xcode and relaunch it but still got same errors.

Comment: @WilliamX Where do you get this information? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 23):

> the cert is installed and valid

That doesn't matter. New in Xcode 13, if you choose Automatic signing, Apple tries to do cloud-based signing; it doesn't even *see* the certificate that's on your computer.

But you do not have the cloud-based signing privilege, so it fails.

You have two choices:

- Get the privilege. It is really worth it, because cloud-based signing is great! It allows you to distribute from an archive to App Store Connect without having any distribution identity or distribution certificate at all. This totally solves the problem that there's only one distribution certificate at a time.
- Switch to manual signing. Now the distribution certificate on your computer will be used. You'll need explicit access to the distribution profile too, obviously; the *whole* export resigning will be manual. That might be simplest if you're in a hurry.

Comment: But shouldn't it still work as the [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes) state "[...] If you already have a valid distribution signing certificate and matching provisioning profiles installed on your Mac, Xcode uses those and signs locally rather than using cloud signing. [...]"?

Comment: @chkpnt Very good point, but my experience is that that isn't how they actually implemented it. I could be wrong, though. Anyway, I've switched to cloud-based signing and I think it's great.

Comment: Tip: if you get yourself access to the cloud-managed Developer ID cert and run into a new error "Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate", you might need to remove your _old_ Developer ID certificate from your Keychain. This will make Xcode use the cloud-managed one that it helpfully added to the provisioning profile that it generated.

Comment: @TomHamming Nice one, that could be crucial.

Comment: I have two machines. Both have the same OS version, the same Xcode version and the same certificates installed with the same private keys. One (the Intel Mac) can upload a build while the other (the M1 Mac) gives me this error...

Answer (score 4):

At least in Xcode 15 I managed to upload a version with manual signing this way:

- Xcode's Organizer
- Select your build to upload
- Click on distribute
- Click on **Custom**
- Just follow the signing process and it will let you perform manual signing

Comment: Since Xcode add these new options, I didn't realize that the processe to distribute is a bit different. When I choose Enterprise direct, I get the permission problem. But when I choose Custom > Enterprise (the old way) I don't get problems anymore.
Thanks @crom87

Comment: @crom87 Thanks! Saved my day. Custom flow and manual signing did it for me. I was able to manually select a cert in my keychain that apple for whatever reason was unable to find.

Comment: Shiny new options I completely ignore the custom option. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I haved this error, because new conditions must be accepted on app store connect : [image]

Comment: This is what worked for me. You can find this message on app store connect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, 2 accounts (Admin and Developer roles respectively) belonging in the same team were logged-in in the Xcode **Accounts** settings. Even though the cloud signing permission for the Developer role was given and the Xcode build settings are properly set for automatic signing, the error persisted.

After **deleted the Admin account** in the settings, the error no longer appeared and the archive could be successfully uploaded. Perhaps Xcode had trouble resolving cloud signing when 2 logged-in accounts both have the signing permissions.

Comment: This is the issue I was facing, I had two account logged in xcode, Removing one solved the issue. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the error messages persist even though the steps are completed for the **Developer role**:

```
Go to App Store Connect
Select the "Users and Access" tab.
Select the correct person and under "Additional Resources" check both.
Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and
Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate Access.
```

From a **Admin Role** perspective, this is incomprehensible and leads to guesswork for some. But the following led to the goal:

1. **Developer Role**: close Xcode
2. **Admin Role**: change the role of the user from "developer" to "admin" temporarily
3. **Developer Role**: restart Xcode and start the validation/distribution process again. it should run successfully
4. **Developer Role**: close Xcode
5. **Admin Role**: set the user's role back to "developer".
6. **Developer Role**: restart Xcode and start the validation/distribution process again. it should run successfully

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem.
The account has permission, but it cannot be exported
After trying many methods, you can finally give the account management permission, and then change back to the developer permission to export normally.
Suspect cloud service cache problem.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to my provisioning profile as well as the certificate issue.

step 1. Create a new certificate in XCode -> Preferences -> + button
step 2. Go to apple developer portal.
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/add
step 3. select iOS App Development, select the app you name, then select the most certificate created in step 1.

After that I restarted XCode and instead of automatic signing I selected manual and had it set to the profile I just created in step 3 for both debug and release settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not one has mentioned that you do need a "Developer ID" Application certificate to be able to upload app for developer ID (or notarized by apple). I ran into this issue, when developing for a relative new developer account. So "Developer ID" has not been set up. You can just go to Xcode account, select the develop Apple ID account, and then select "Manage Certificate". Select "Developer ID Application" certificate.

This solved my issue. It's possible you need login with the account that has the admin or account holder privilege to be able to perform the above operations. This was what I did though.