# The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode14

The following error occurs when I upload my app to App Store Connect:

```
The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value

'' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: Having an identical problem. I don't think it's the bundle version string. And as a side note, if it IS something as simple as the version string being in the wrong format, why doesn't "validate" catch it, and even more to-the-point, why in the 21st century do we have such an absolutely meaningless piece of diagnostic feedback message?

@Cihan Kalmaz, were you able to overcome this?

Comment: yes i think so. Apple must fix this asap.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the version is correct and i have no capabilities. The app is already published but after upgrade to xcode 14 i have this error.

Comment: downgrade.to xcode 13

Comment: This seems like something related to apple. This is happening to me for an already uploaded app

Comment: I happen to be facing this relationship issue on a Valentine's Day.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This error can occur when using an invalid version string. Please ensure that your app uses the following format for your **'Bundle version string (short)'** and **'bundle version'** strings
[number].[number].[number] in your info

You can find this fields Runner > Info section

Comment: I must eat crow. Fixing the short version did in fact help. I hit another roadblock pretty quick, but you were right in my case. Mine was actually blank in info.plist.

Comment: Yes same for me, fixed the issue. But why is an explicit short string required when I check Manage Build Number and my short version gets overridden anyway?

Comment: never trust xcode, never.

Comment: you can also find it in Xcode as visually explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921249/4833705

Answer (score 23):

I just had the same issue happen to me. Didn't make any changes and just retried the upload. It worked. Go figure.

Comment: This worked for me. Adding also the fact that the same version was in review. So I cancelled review first and reuploaded new version.

Comment: The same. Just keep retrying and praying.

Comment: The same but with a `flutter clean` just in case.

Answer (score 20):

The upload was successful after agreeing to the latest Program License Agreement in my developer account.

Comment: This is Same for me.

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: The same! Lost 3 hours of my life because of this stupidity.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

1. Install the Transporter app from the MacOS app store
2. From Xcode's organizer select your archive and press Distribute App
3. Select Export and proceed as usual
4. Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press Deliver

Hope this method helps!

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this error when I ticked the "Manage Version and Builder Number" checkbox in the "App Store Connect distribution options" popup. (See screenshot below.) After unticking this checkbox and retrying the upload, it worked.

[image: Add Store Connect distribution options checkbox]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

Quit XCode.
Open XCode again with the project.
Go to XCode -> Project Menu -> Clean Build Folder.
Archive project again.
And it worked.

Comment: This worked after incrementing the build number as well.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the Apple ID account in Xcode and re-adding solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

This issue maybe related to Apple agreement. You must accept agreement before you can upload new app version. I had the same issue and just checked and found this. [image]

Answer (score 2):

**Check your manage certificate**

**follow this process:**

-> Go Xcode>Settings>Account select your user then manage the certificate if there is error you can hover error icon like below screenshot, there will display the toast regarding the error.

I had agreement acceptance issue.

Hope you got the solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

for me, I had to go to the https://developer.apple.com/account and sign a new agreement. This error was a total red herring! If you're sure you're inputting a valid build and version number (like I was), try checking if you have any pending agreements

Comment: Yes, same for me, an Apple developer agreement needed confirmation. XCode and App Store Connect are positively kafkaesque.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened for me when my current version of the app was in `In Review` state:

> The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value - You cannot create a new version of the App in the current state. - /data/relationships/app

I just needed to wait for approve and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION...
Remove non-numeric characters from TARGETS > General > Identity > Version.

PROBLEM...
I had appended "a" to my Identity Version "37.7a"
Changing back to "37.7" fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug when my app version was rejected. I had to cancel the submission. It worked after cancellation.

Answer (score 1):

change the app status to "Prepare for Submission" in App Store Connect

Answer (score 1):

This issue may arise due to Apple's requirements and agreements. Before being able to upload the new version of the application, developers need to accept the terms and conditions outlined in Apple's agreement. I encountered a similar issue, and upon investigation, I realized that accepting the agreement is a crucial step to resolve this problem `[update 2024]`

You can find at: `AppStore`> Add new `IOS APP +` >go to link popup `Apple Developer Website` and `Agree`

Go to view full: [How to fix the provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value - update 2024](https://einternet.net/2024/01/29/how-to-fix-the-provided-entity-includes-a-relationship-with-an-invalid-value-update-2024/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Go to info tab and change the bundle version to Number. Bundle version should be your app version.

Answer (score 0):

So from the below image if 1.0 is ready for sale and you are trying to upload 1.1 it will not work. I needed to create 1.1 version from the appstoreconnect.  Then it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue, you have to enable the Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate.

Go to:
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users

then select the desired user -> under Additional Resources, check both:

- Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
- Access to Cloud Managed Distribution Certificate.

I don't know why the error message is irrelevant to the issue, but that is why I spent 5 days fixing it,

check it here for more information:
[App Store Connect Upload Error "You haven't been given access to cloud-managed distribution certificates"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609859/app-store-connect-upload-error-you-havent-been-given-access-to-cloud-managed-d)

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me:**

**Step1.** Goto Tab General set Version=1.0, Build=1

**Step2.** Goto Tab Info  set Bundle version=1, Bundle version string (short)=2.2.2  ****At step upload will display 2.2.2(1)

**Step 3**. Change location temp file ( or delete temp file DerivedData, Archives )

Goto Xcode => Preferences => Locations

**Step 4.** Login App Store Connect

**Step 5**. Archives Again. Upload is success.

---

My Error message
[image]

Step1. Goto Tab General

set Version = 1.0

set Build = 1

[image]

Step2. Goto Tab Info

set Bundle version = 1

set Bundle version string (short) = 2.2.2

****At step upload will display 2.2.2(1)

[image]

Step 3. Change location temp file ( or delete temp file DerivedData, Archives )

Goto Xcode => Preferences => Locations

[image]
[image]

Step 4. Login App Store Connect

Step 5. Archives Again.

Upload is success.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I just needed to change or increment Current Project Version and Marketing Version.
You can find it in your Apps target -> Build Settings -> Versioning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

goto ios distrubition list and remove the existing pending release.[image]