# The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value when uploading to App Store Connect

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect

my app passes validation but when uploading to App store connect, im getting this error:
`The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value " is not a valid id for the relationship 'build' (ID: 80XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)`

[image]

There is even no logs to be able to know whats wrong.
I saw similar issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74163395/the-provided-entity-includes-a-relationship-with-an-invalid-value) and they are talking about `Bundle version string`
Here is my **bundle version string**

[image]
[image]

Is there something wrong with my bundle version string ?
I tried to change my bundle version string inside info.plist file to this:
`<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key> <string>1.0.0</string>`

But still, I get the same error.
Appreciated much if someone could help.

Comment: @bizz84 yes its a duplicate but the cause of the error is different. I solved it though by unchecking the `Background processing` under capabilities and re-configure the `appIcon`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the version is correct and i have no capabilities. The app is already published but after upgrade to xcode 14 i have this error.

Comment: Same exact error for me. Any solution?

Comment: @DanielZanchi it's frustrating that the `Validate` doesn't catch the error. it took me 2 days to find out the cause was the `background processing` was checked under capabilities. there are many reasons that may trigger this error, but try to check whether it might also be the case for you.

Comment: Hi, @john I face the same issues, In my case session is expired with app store so archive was validated successfully but gave same problems.

Comment: @DavideC I *think* I saw and fixed this same problem in Xcode 14.2 by going to Xcode Preferences - Accounts - AppleID - Manage Certificates and generating a new "Mac Installer Distribution" certificate as the old one had expired 2 years ago. I guess Xcode 14 started requiring it, as I had released a few months ago ok. Had to clear all cache and rebuild a new archive few times before the error went away completely and I was able to submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74163395/the-provided-entity-includes-a-relationship-with-an-invalid-value)

Comment: @MaxMacLeod no, The error is very generic and a lot of factors can trigger it. I already seen that thread and tried evrything before posting this. Solved it anyway by unchecking the background processing in Xcode and reuploaded appIcon.

Comment: Hello @john great that you solved it. Please, if you provide details by answering your own question. You will gain reputation and we can vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error for me was the Background Processing option being enabled in Background Modes (found in Xcode -> Project -> Capabilities). An improperly configured App Icon can also trigger this error. The solution involved two steps:

· Uncheck the Background Processing option in Background Modes.

· Reupload the correct App Icon.

If you're facing the same error, try this solution to see if it works for you. Always ensure you're meeting all specific requirements of your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my current situation, I am archiving the existing app, a process that has been successful in the past but is triggering an issue now. My solution is to proceed to the 'Product' tab and click the 'Clean Build Folder' option, and everything works like a charm.